# Swift UI - Path Not Contained Within Frame

Tags: swiftui

I am creating a simple path between two coordinates (`[100, 100]`, `[300, 300]`) and I want the frame of that path to be only the size it needs to be (i.e., 200 x 200). For some reason, while the frame shrinks to the desired 200 x 200 size, the path starts being drawn in the middle of the frame and therefore overflows.

How can I centre the path within a frame? I tried assigning `alignment: .topLeading` on the path frame parameter but that didn't change anything.

Code:

```
struct RelationView: View {
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300)
    
    var body: some View {
        Path({ path in
            path.addLines([
                startPoint,
                CGPoint(x: (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2, y: startPoint.y),
                CGPoint(x: (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2, y: endPoint.y),
                endPoint
            ])
        })
            .stroke()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: iPad Preview of Frame and Path]

Comment: Why don't you just adjust your start point to `0,0` and end point to `200,200`? Starting at a point other than the origin and then wanting the frame to shrink to that size seems like an overly-complicated scenario for something where you could just transpose the values.

Comment: That sounds like the way to go. I haven't thought of it but I'll update my code start from 0,0 instead. Thanks

Comment: Path is drawing in coordinate space of parent, here parent is view framed 200x200, so path is drawn as expected, because 100x100 is a center of framed view, and 300x300 is outside (view is not clipped, so drawing outside is visible).